# Install Tensorflow in virtual environment python 2.7

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, virtualenv, six

Please, how can i install Tensorflow in a virtual environment? I have used these commands but it doesn't work..

```
sudo -H pip3 install tensorflow  --proxy https://XXX.XX.XX.X:3128

sudo -E pip3 install tensorflow  --proxy https://XXX.XX.XX.X:3128

sudo -E pip install tensorflow  --proxy https://XXX.XX.XX.X:3128

sudo -H pip install tensorflow  --proxy https://XXX.XX.XX.X:3128

sudo  pip install tensorflow  --proxy https://XXX.XX.XX.X:3128
```

It resulted in:

```
Downloading/unpacking tensorflow
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

These are my python and pip versions:

```
(venv)root@graphene-62:~/tensorflow# pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
(python 2.7)
(venv)root@graphene-62:~/tensorflow# python -V
Python 2.7.6
```

After I tried `pip install -U tensorflow`, I got the following result:

```
Cannot uninstall 'six'
```

Then I tried `pip install -U tensorflow --ignore-installed six`, and with the tf version check I got:

```
(venv)root@graphene-62:~/tensorflow# python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)" 
Illegal instruction (core dumped) (venv)root@graphene-62:~/tensorflow#
```

Is there another way to download and install Tensorflow?

Comment: On which python version do you want TensorFlow? You are using the commands for both 3.* and 2.* versions..

Comment: in the (venv)  --> pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
(python 2.7)       @marcuse

Comment: @marcuse  any recent version of Tensorflow

Comment: @marcuse   pyhton -V  --> 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that your pip version is up to date with:

```
pip install -U pip
```

Then, as per the comments and edited question, execute:

```
pip install -U tensorflow==1.5.0 --ignore-installed six
```

This will ignore the `six` related error and the slightly downgraded tensorflow package will install and be useable without the Illegal Instruction error.

To check if the installation was successfull, execute:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
```

Comment: The first command works fine. With the second command i have:   Cannot uninstall 'six'. It is a distutils installed project and thus
we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would
lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: >>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Comment: Try `pip install -U tensorflow --ignore-installed six`

Comment: in the (venv)       (venv)root@graphene-62:~/tensorflow# python -c "import tensorflow as
tf; print(tf.__version__)"
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
(venv)root@graphene-62:~/tensorflow#

Comment: Ah, I think we're almost there. First execute `pip uninstall -U tensorflow`
and then `pip install -U tensorflow==1.5.0 --ignore-installed six`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177169/discussion-between-marcuse-and-user1543915).

Comment: (venv)root@graphene-62:~/tensorflow# sudo python -c "import tensorflow
as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
1.5.0      Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help! Can you mark this question as solved?

Comment: Done :) thnks :)

Answer (score 0):

Recently, `pip install tensorflow` with python 2.7 might cause the error message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tensorflow

You can instead install TensorFlow with:

```
pip install -U https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

You can replace the URL of the wheel with some other URLs from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Same issue with `tensorflow-gpu`.